# < converted to &lt; in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have some data in my table

when i select that data with this query

```
select TblActionHistories.Comments from TblActionHistories WHERE TblActionHistories.Entity=CAST('Task' AS VARCHAR) AND EntityId=CAST(32 AS VARCHAR)
```

it's coming fine like this

```
Task- <b>T1</b> has been added by Swapnil Sharma
Task- <b>T1</b> status changed to <b>In Progress</b> by Swapnil Sharma<br/>
```

but now i want my above result # separated using `stuff` so i am using this

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '#' + ISNULL(CAST(TblActionHistories.Comments AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'') FROM TblActionHistories WHERE TblActionHistories.Entity=CAST('Task' AS VARCHAR) AND EntityId=CAST(32 AS VARCHAR) for xml path ('')),1,1,'')
```

it gives me this

```
Task- &lt;b&gt;T1&lt;/b&gt; has been added by Swapnil Sharma#Task- &lt;b&gt;T1&lt;/b&gt; status changed to &lt;b&gt;In Progress&lt;/b&gt; by Swapnil Sharma&lt;br/&gt;
```

you can clearly see that all the special char. like < > converted to `&lt; &gt;` respectively

please help me out with this i want them to come in their original format

Comment: Then you shouldn't be converting them to XML. So your question should really be "what's a good way to concatenate row values whilst avoiding converting the text to XML?"

Comment: I believe it's because of FOR XML, take a look at this article: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2012/06/08/24296.aspx

Comment: link no longer works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i found the solution as suggested by IvanG

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '#' + ISNULL(CAST(TblActionHistories.Comments AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'') FROM TblActionHistories WHERE TblActionHistories.Entity=CAST('Task' AS VARCHAR) AND EntityId=CAST(32 AS VARCHAR) for xml path(''), root('MyString'), type ).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') ,1,1,'')
```

ref. to this article

http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/

Answer (score -2):

Try casting to NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '#' + ISNULL(CAST(TblActionHistories.Comments AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'') FROM TblActionHistories WHERE TblActionHistories.Entity=CAST('Task' AS NVARCHAR) AND EntityId=CAST(32 AS VARCHAR) for xml path ('')),1,1,'')
```